# What is the best way cross-browser to trim an element innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way cross-browser to trim an element `innerHTML`? 
**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hk8z/**

Comment: What do you mean by "trim"?

Comment: Trim - strip whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: What does that have to do with `innerHTML`? There's not even a whitespace in your fiddle example string.

Comment: How to remove unnecessary space? http://jsfiddle.net/6hk8z/3/

Comment: What space is unnecessary? And still, the string `Test &nbsp; <br>` does not have any whitespace in the beginning or end (it starts with a `T` and ends with a `>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting confused with the `&nbsp;` html code that is not whitespace but merely rendered as such by the  browser.  See customised implementation below:

```
String.prototype.trimmed = function(){
    return this.replace(
        /^(\s|&nbsp;|<br\s*\/?>)+?|(\s|&nbsp;|<br\s*\/?>)+?$/ig, ' '
    ).trim();
}
```

updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hk8z/7/)

Comment: Ok,but try to delete the text in the div and insert 3 blank spaces. Then click on the div.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at, if you trim string containing only whitespace you get an empty string.

Comment: Do not overwrite the native `String.prototype.trim` method!

Comment: It is created automatically <br> if you try to change the text (br not necessary). How to remove it?

Comment: @Bergi ye probably a bad example but my tired brain is struggling to come up with an apt function name :(

Comment: @Emissary doesn't work. "Test" and two (empty) break line return "Test<br><br><br>" and "Test    " return "Test    <br>".

Comment: @user2719515 it only checked for a single solitary line-break - you need to be quite specific about your requirements otherwise we're just guessing... `<br/>` has context.  In any case - I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/6hk8z/7/) again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM, not `innerHTML` which you would need to parse.

```
function trimContents(element) {
    function iterate(start, sibling, reg) {
        for(var next, c = element[start]; c != null; c=next) {
            next = c[sibling];
            if (c.nodeType == 1 && c.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "br"
             || c.nodeType == 3 && !(c.nodeValue = c.nodeValue.replace(reg, "")))
                element.removeChild(c);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    iterate("firstChild", "nextSibling", /^\s+/);
    iterate("lastChild", "previousSibling", /\s+$/);
}
```

([demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/6hk8z/6/))

Comment: that's actually quite neat but it only works on the first click for me (chrome) - I've never bothered with `contenteditable`; seems to have some quirky behaviour (adding loads of divs).

Comment: @Emissary: So you want it to remove empty divs as well?

Comment: No mate, it would be overkill and outside of the scope of the question. Generally speaking I'd argue that if someone wanted to trim outer DOM elements from a string they are taking the wrong approach to begin with? I'm not even sure I would consider `<br/>` or carriage returns as "whitespace" either, OP flagged that a BR was being added in place of an empty string - I was just pointing out that it's a result of how the browser is handling the `contenteditable` attribute which may or may not differ cross-browser - just seemed like a bit of a headache.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried jQuery's `$.trim()`? See jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) for more details.

Comment: Question doesn't stipulate jQuery - totally unnecessary.